unique key constraint not working in cosmos [ef core]
I am define unique key for cosmos in my AppDbContext like below
    builder.Entity<StKeyValueStore>()
        .ToContainer(nameof(StKeyValueStore))
        .HasPartitionKey(x => x.PartitionKey)
        .HasNoDiscriminator()
        .HasIndex(x => new { x.Key }).IsUnique();

But I am still able to insert duplicate Key in the collection... the PartitionKey = "default" for all the collection entries.
Below are the values inserted in collection
{
    "Id": "92c373cc-0272-4ca9-b789-e5734c32e2fa",
    "PartitionKey": "default",
    "Key": "key1",
    "Value": "value1",
    "id": "92c373cc-0272-4ca9-b789-e5734c32e2fa",
    "_rid": "p2Y6AKgpcx8BAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/p2Y6AA==/colls/p2Y6AKgpcx8=/docs/p2Y6AKgpcx8BAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"05005d06-0000-2000-0000-668278a10000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1719826593
}

and value 2
{
    "Id": "9592412f-98ba-42fb-9ecf-bb047a800990",
    "PartitionKey": "default",
    "Key": "key1",
    "Value": "value2",
    "id": "9592412f-98ba-42fb-9ecf-bb047a800990",
    "_rid": "p2Y6AKgpcx8CAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/p2Y6AA==/colls/p2Y6AKgpcx8=/docs/p2Y6AKgpcx8CAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"05005e06-0000-2000-0000-668278a10000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1719826593
}


Still opened issue, probably you should do that by yourself.
